# How to update the set size of alloy model to be in a certain range?

Tags: alloy

If I have an Alloy model in the following format

```
one sig player {
    name: String,
    spot: set  position
}

sig position {
    Attack: Bool,
    accuracy: int,
    strength: int,

}
```

If I want to have a cetain rule such that each player can have 1 to 3 positions. Is there a way to create such a prediction or fact to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an appended fact to the `player` sig to specify that constraint.  The cardinality operator (`#`) can be used to express the "set size" e.g.,

```
one sig player {
    name: String,
    spot: set  position
} {
    #position <= 1 && position >= 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I specify that one player's positions are different from each other. For example, if one player has two position. The attack of one position is True. then the other position can not have attack to be True.

Comment: Can I use the following pred: all n: shippingServiceOptions, m: shippingServiceOptions - n {
  n.expeditedService not in m.expeditedService
 }

Comment: @user2744486, you might want to pose those questions as new questions; they really aren't comments on the solution offered to the problem you posed above.